# Console Application Publish and include content files along

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, console-application, publish

I am trying to publish a console application, that has a few data `(.csv)` files in the project.

I set the files to `copy if newer` and `build action` as  `content`, and hoped that they will get copied with the publish procedure. which certainly isnt the case.

The location of the files that console application looks for resides in AppData/****RANDOM/path, hence I cant copy these files manually.

Can you please suggest me a way to include these files along with the publish process?

PS: I am trying to stick to Publish process, but if that is not the best to use in this scenario I am more than happy to use something else that works.

Answer (score 0):

if you are publishing a installer then you can include it inside

if you are publishing a zip you can zip it inside

if you have to stick with one single .exe file then you could use the application resources. Right click on the project and select properties -> Resources. This will embed the csv inside your .exe file and you can either read it directly or copy it somewhere else.

Comment: `if you are publishing a installer then you can include it inside` can you please tell me how

Comment: and how do we create one single exe for the console app ?

Comment: @Muds its different depending on what installer package program you are using. You will have one single exe if you are not using any dlls. If you are then you can package them together using some other program

Comment: there is a .net publish method that you can easily do, i wanted to include files with it

Comment: @Muds That is using click once. you can find the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx  seems like you only have to change the build action to content for it to work